# Insert multiple related table from sqlalchemy ORM in 1 session.commit()

Tags: python, mysql, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

i have 3 tables as follow:

```
+----A----+  +----B----+  +----C----+
|id_a   PK|  |id_b   PK|  |id_c   PK|
|other1   |  |id_a   FK|  |id_a   FK|
|other2   |  |other3   |  |other4   |
+---------+  +---------+  +---------+
```

with sqlalchemy ORM:

```
class Model_A(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "A"

    id_a = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    other1 = db.Column(db.String)
    other2 = db.Column(db.String)

    # relationships
    rel_B= db.relationship('Model_B', backref='A', lazy='dynamic')
    rel_c = db.relationship('Model_C', backref='A', lazy='dynamic')

    @orm.reconstructor
    def init_on_load(self):
        # private
        pass

    def __init__(self):
        # private
        pass

    def input_data(self):
        # how do i input data to all of the 3 tables in 1 db.session.commit()


class Model_B(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "B"

    id_b = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    id_a= db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('A.id_a'))
    other3 = db.Column(db.String)

    @orm.reconstructor
    def init_on_load(self):
        # private
        pass

    def __init__(self):
        # private
        pass

class Model_C(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "C"

    id_c = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    id_a= db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('A.id_a'))
    other4 = db.Column(db.String)

    @orm.reconstructor
    def init_on_load(self):
        # private
        pass

    def __init__(self):
        # private
        pass
```

*** field `other4` in table C will be inserted as the newly inserted id_a ***

I try to insert data to those table as 1 activity.
at the moment below is what i did: in `def input_data` from `class Model_A`

```
def input_data(self):
    try:
        self.rel_B.append(Model_B(other3='some data'))
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()
        return {'status': True, 'data': {'message': 'Some Message'}}
    except Exception as e:
        log.info('>>>>> Exception: %s <<<<<', e)
        return {'status': False, 'message': e}

    input_data_to_c()

def input_data_to_c(self):
    try:
        self.rel_C.append(Model_C(other4=self.id_a))
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()
        return {'status': True, 'data': {'message': 'Some Message'}}
    except Exception as e:
        log.info('>>>>> Exception: %s <<<<<', e)
        return {'status': False, 'message': e}
```

above code is work, but i realize that there are 2 commits here.

***questions:***

is there a way to insert in multiple db using sqlalchemy ORM in 1 session.commit?

and how to insert newly inserted id to another column (in my case above is `other4`

Cheers,